# SQLite insertion failure in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, caching, wolframalpha

I'm trying to create a simple cache using SQLite for certain queries against WolframAlpha's API in Python. The problem is that the SQLite INSERT fails for certain queries, and I really don't know why.

At http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/explorer.html it is possible to run exactly the two queries I ran. They are:

```
nutritional information of coke
```

and

```
nutritional information of milk
```

The INSERT for the first query works great, but the second fails.

Here's the code that takes care of the caching functionality:

```
def run_query(input_query):
    input_query = query_stub + input_query
    cursor.execute('SELECT response FROM cache WHERE query=?', (input_query,))
    response = cursor.fetchone()

    if response:
        print " Cache hit on: %s" % (input_query)
        response = response[0]
    else:
        print " Cache miss on: %s" % (input_query)
        query = waeo.CreateQuery(input_query)
        print '1'
        response = waeo.PerformQuery(query)
        print '2'
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO cache VALUES (?, ?)', (input_query, response,))
        print '3'
        conn.commit()
        print '4'

    output_json = xmltodict.parse(response)
    return jsonify(output_json)
```

The table is defined as:

```
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE cache (query text, response text)')
```

And here are part of the logs, so as you can see, the INSERT is failing:

```
    * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    Cache miss on: nutritional information of coke
1
2
3
4
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Sep/2013 17:51:16] "GET /wa?item=coke HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    Cache miss on: nutritional information of milk
1
2
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Sep/2013 17:51:47] "GET /wa?item=milk HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: If you're saying `cursor.execute` fails, it should raise an exception, can you catch that an see what it says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as dwxw suggested and found out that there was an encoding error. It seems like the results from one of the queries contained non-ASCII characters.

> You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings

I searched around and found that this was most easily solved by simply adding the following line (conn is my SQLite connection):

> conn.text_factory = str

Thanks for the tip, dwxw. I don't know how I didn't think of that myself...